# Fluctuations in execution time, is this normal?

Tags: performance, execution-time

I'm trying to implement some sort of template matching which requires me calling a function more than 10 thousand times per frame. I've managed to reduce the execution time of my function to a few microseconds. However, about 1 in 5 executions will take quite longer to run. While the function usually runs in less than 20 microseconds these cases can even take 100 microseconds.

Trying to find the part of the function that has fluctuating execution time, I realized that big fluctuations appear in many parts, almost randomly. And this "ghost" time is added even in parts that take constant time. For example, iterating through a specific number of vectors and taking their dot product with a specific vector fluctuates from 3 microseconds to 20+.

All the tests I did seem to indicate that the fluctuation has nothing to do with the varying data but instead it's just random at some parts of the code. Of course I could be wrong and maybe all these parts that have fluctuations contain something that causes them. But my main question is specific and that's why I don't provide a snippet or runtime data:

**Are fluctuations of execution time from 3 microseconds to 20+ microseconds for constant time functions with the same amount of data normal? Could the cpu occasionally be doing something else that is causing these ghost times?**

Comment: *Could the cpu occasionally be doing something else...?* Of course it could be. What O/S do you have? Is your code running in high-priority or "real time" mode?

Comment: @AdrianMole I'm using W10 and I'm just running this on VS on release. I've never had to count my code in microseconds before so it's the first time I come across such questions. Could I somehow give priority to my code?

Comment: Multiple reasons for fluctuations, but yes they can happen. That's why you have OS's and RTOS's (Realtime OS's). On most OS's there's multithreading, no guarantee you will get (enough) access to your CPU all the time

Comment: John yes you could give priority, but it's opening a can of worms. There's always something else that wants more priority then you. Or you set it too high and nothing else works as it should

Comment: @PKramer How would I do this in VS? You don't have to explain the whole thing, just some keywords so I know what to search. Thank you.

Comment: This one gives a start : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/scheduling-priorities, but trust me in the end I usually had to find other solutions.